# How does the UP Columbus Twin-Barrel work?

Tags: savage-worlds, interface-zero

it says this:

> Pop, Pop, Double Tap! Nothing is sexier than a big pistol, and
>   the Columbus is 9 pounds of Black Steel. It has an innovative
>   design configuration, with the top barrel firing, then the
>   bottom barrel, reducing the kick from the double barrels. The
>   unique clip design does have some flaws, it can jam easily,
>   yet every shot is a Double Tap (see Savage Worlds core rules).

Does that mean that every shot is a Double Tap? Isn't that bad? This gun costs 2500 which is really expensive for a gun like this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the quoted section means every shot is a double tap. 
In the core Savage Worlds rules, Double Tap provides +1 to the Shooting result and +1 to the damage total at the cost of two pieces of ammunition.

*Effectively*, the Columbus Twin-Barrel has 6 "shots", +1 Shooting, and deals an effective 2d6+2 damage. This makes it accurate and powerful but it goes through ammunition unusually quickly.